# Can the results of my search be links to pages?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, search

I have a search engine on my ASP.net 4.0 VB site that in which I need to link the search results with their individual pages. I understand that this can be done simply with a submit button after the search textbox but a submit button wouldn't fit next to the search bar on my page, plus it wouldn't look right. [image: This is a screenshot of the search engine.]

The old way, the results were stored in a hidden div where they became links to their pages. I was hoping that the code I have of the old search could be incorporated into the new search, but I do not know where it would go. The only way I can think of to do it is to place the code in the webservice in a while or for loop. I may be way off base here, but that is why I am asking what the best way to go about this would be?

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetCompletionList(ByVal prefixText As String, ByVal count As Integer) As String()
    Dim ProductSql As String = "Select ProductName FROM Product WHERE ProductName LIKE '" & prefixText & "%'"
    Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection
    sqlConn.Open()
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(ProductSql, sqlConn)
    Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
    Dim myTable As New DataTable
    myTable.TableName = "ProductSearch"
    myTable.Load(myReader)
    sqlConn.Close()
    Dim items As String() = New String(myTable.Rows.Count - 1) {}
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each dr As DataRow In myTable.Rows
        items.SetValue(dr("ProductName").ToString(), i)
        i += 1
    Next
    Return items
End Function

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="ProductSearch.asmx" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Search" runat="server" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Search" ServicePath="~/ProductSearch.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionSetCount="120" EnableCaching="true" CompletionListCssClass="results">
    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Comment: Never use string concatenation in SQL queries. You should use a SqlCommand object with parameters. HUGE script injection vulnerability in your code!

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I forgot to mention that. I know that my code has SQL Injection vulnerabilities, I just want the site to work. Once I get the site to work, I will go back and make all the code safe. I don't know anything about sql injection or preventing it, so I will research that once everything is done. :) Thanks though!

Comment: @jlg, SQL injection in short, can allow the attacker to delete all the records in your database. So do read up on it for sure!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a little javascript to make links out of the results of my search engine query. This is what I have now - although the For Each loop in the Web Service doesn't work properly.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript">
function AutoCompleteClientMethod(source, eventArgs) {
    var value = eventArgs.get_value();
    window.location = ("/Product/Default.aspx?id=" + value)
} 
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="ProductSearch.asmx" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Search" runat="server" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Search" ServicePath="~/ProductSearch.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetProducts" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionSetCount="120" EnableCaching="true" OnClientItemSelected="AutoCompleteClientMethod">
    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
</asp:Content>


<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetProducts(ByVal prefixText As String, ByVal count As Integer) As String()
    Dim ProductSql As String = "Select ProductID, ProductName FROM Product WHERE ProductName LIKE '" & prefixText & "%'"
    Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection
    sqlConn.Open()
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(ProductSql, sqlConn)
    Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
    Dim myTable As New DataTable
    myTable.TableName = "ProductSearch"
    myTable.Load(myReader)
    sqlConn.Close()
    Dim items As String() = New String(myTable.Rows.Count - 1) {}
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each dr As DataRow In myTable.Rows
        items.SetValue(dr("ProductName").ToString(), i)
        i += 1
    Next
    Return items
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: You're going to want your SqlConnection, SqlCOmmanad and SqlDataReader to be in `Using` blocks.